# Killing vectors in Minkowsky Metric

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, vector-fields, causality

So I was in the process to find the Killing vectors for the Minkowsky Metric and I stumbbled into a material that does a different procedure at the very end of the process, in comparisson to usual books and articles I've seen. The resoning goes as follows:

For example, suppose we have found the Killing vector

$$
K=x \frac{\partial}{\partial_t} + t\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}
$$

**The way I would check this is a generator for the boost in the x direction** is by acting these vectors onto $t$ and $x$ and check they give, respectively, x and t.

**The way this material I've found does** is, they suddenly deffine:

$$
\Lambda=\exp[\lambda(x \frac{\partial}{\partial_t} + t\frac{\partial}{\partial_x})]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\lambda^n (x \frac{\partial}{\partial_t} + t\frac{\partial}{\partial_x})^n
$$

then he proceeds to find the explicit form of the boost:

$$
\Lambda t = x\sinh \lambda +t\cosh \lambda
$$

$$
\Lambda x = t\sinh \lambda +x\cosh \lambda
$$

I understand the steps in this process. What I don't get is where did the motivation for the exponentiation come. What does that mean? It seems to me to have something to do with the application of the diffeomorfisms, but I'm not sure.

Also, would this be a more correct way to proceed then what I've done?I really would appreciate any comments on this, as well as reccomended material.

Comment: The exponential map, from the tangent plane to the actual spacetime, is an actual exponential function in Minkowski space. You can show it by working out the geodesic equation at a point using the exponential map.

Comment: This gives me a light about it, and I appreciate. But could you elaborate more? I am really new to those concepts. I couldn't find any material deriving this for Minkowski...